# RxJs - can't create two new Observables from merged one

Tags: javascript, merge, rxjs, behaviorsubject, rxjs-observables

I'm stuck here right now I hope someone can help me :-)

**following scenario:**

I have two streams which transfer the same data type.
The first stream provides initial data (REST call) and completes afterwards.
The second stream gets its data via websocket and does not complete.

```js
const mockData: User[] = [
  { id: '1', status: 'active' },
  { id: '2', status: 'inactive' },
  { id: '3', status: 'active' }
];

const initial$: Observable<User[]> = of(mockData);

const sub$: BehaviorSubject<User[]> = new BehaviorSubject(mockData);
const dynamic$ = sub$.asObservable();
```

Now I want to merge both streams and create two new streams based on a filter criterion, one for the active and one for the deactivated users.

```js
const merged$ = merge(initial$, dynamic$).pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b))
);

const grouped$ = merged$.pipe(
  mergeMap((users: User[]) => from(users)),
  tap(a => console.log('Before group by', a)),
  groupBy(item => item.status),
  tap(a => console.log('After group by', a.key)),
  mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray()))),
  tap(a => console.log('after merge map', a))
);

const activeByGrouped$ = grouped$.pipe(
  filter(([key]) => key === 'active'),
  map(([key, value]) => value)
);

activeByGrouped$.subscribe(a => console.log('final subscribe', a));
```

The whole thing works if both streams complete, but not if one is open.
Attached is a stackblitz for better understanding.

**>> stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ixc3nu <<**

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of what you want to achieve is that you want to have a stream of only active/inactive users. In this case `toArray()` is not a good choice because it requires the source Observable to complete which never happens when you're using Subjects (unless you call `complete()` yourself).

So it appears you could just restructure your chain. However, you can't collect all results and then emit one large array (because again you the source doesn't complete). You could also emit all intermediate results using `scan()` but it depends what behavior you want:

```
const grouped$ = merged$.pipe(
  mergeMap((users: User[]) => from(users)),
  groupBy(item => item.status),
);

const activeByGrouped$ = grouped$.pipe(
  filter(group => group.key === 'active'),
  mergeMap(group => group)
);
```

Your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-evvehx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need a list of objects per active / inactive observable, so the zip operator is a step in the right direction. However this accumulates the values, but I need another functionality, explained below. ->

I always get from the backend a complete list of valid values, so always a list of objects. The previous transmitted values are from then on invalid as soon as the backend sends a new list.

Comment: Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees - It was easier than expected **working demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jelf1d)**

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees - It was easier than expected.

```js
interface User {
  id: string;
  status: 'active' | 'inactive';
}

const mockData: User[] = [
  { id: '1', status: 'active' },
  { id: '2', status: 'inactive' },
  { id: '3', status: 'active' }
];

const initial$: Observable<User[]> = of(mockData);

const sub$: BehaviorSubject<User[]> = new BehaviorSubject(mockData);
const dynamic$ = sub$.asObservable();

setTimeout(() => sub$.next([{ id: '1', status: 'active' }]), 2000);

const merged$ = merge(initial$, dynamic$).pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)),
  tap(console.log),
  shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true }),
);

const activeGrouped$ = merged$.pipe(
  map((users: User[]) => users.filter((user: User) => user.status === 'active'))
);

const inactiveGrouped$ = merged$.pipe(
  map((users: User[]) =>
    users.filter((user: User) => user.status === 'inactive')
  )
);

activeGrouped$.subscribe(a => console.log('final subscribe - active:', a));
inactiveGrouped$.subscribe(a => console.log('final subscribe - inactive:', a));
```

**working demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jelf1d)**